# Prevent SignalR ping

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have used `SignalR` in my application for refreshing some portions based on Server broadcast from `Hub`.

But here I am getting some problem that on every 5 mins of interval `Client pings` for connection.
That causes data disappearence. I dont want to use this `SignalR Ping`, because i am already broadcasting on server side to all clients using code::

```
Clients.All.BroadcastNewsCount(ValidNewsCount, SelectedCompany, TypeOfOperation);
```

Below is the screen shot of the Ping::
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The purpose of the /ping request is to keep ASP.NET sessions alive. If you don't need this functionality you can disable the pings by setting `pingInterval` to null in your call to $.connection.hub.start like so:

```
// Disable SignalR pings
$.connection.hub.start({ pingInterval: null })//...
```

Comment: I have tried this but still signalR pings on 5 minutes interval

Comment: Are you sure that it is your app pinging on the 5 minute interval and not [Browser Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) which uses SignalR under the covers? The link I provided explains how you can disable the feature.

Comment: It worked!!  
Problem was on my side that I am using signalR at more than one place.
@halter73 Thanks!!